# Make x the subject of formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm confused about this question, can someone clarify this for me please?

Are both correct answers?

1. $$\frac{x-b}{x-c} = 4$$
   $$ x-b = 4(x-c) $$
   $$x-b = 4x-4c $$
   $$x-4x = b - 4c $$
   $$x(1-4) = b - 4c$$
   $$x(-3) = b - 4c$$
   $$x = \frac{b - 4c}{-3} $$

2.
$$\frac{x-b}{x-c} = 4$$
$$x - b = 4(x-c) $$
$$x-b = 4x - 4c$$
$$4c - b = 4x - x$$
$$4c-b = x(4-1)$$
$$4c - b = x(3)$$
$$\frac{4c-b}{3} = x$$

Comment: Both cyclulations are the same, so one of them is enough. There is, of course, one more restriction, namely $4c-b\neq 3c$, because otherwise $x=c$, and we divide by zero at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, both correct. If you multiply numerator and denominator by -1 in the top result, you see it is the same as the bottom result.

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are indeed correct.  Consider what happens if you took $\frac{b-4c}{-3}$ and multiplied both top and bottom by $-1$.